# Visual Studio 2010 C# Run/Debug on Remote Machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Please excuse my ignorance, I am mainly a Java developer and a bit unfamiliar with Visual Studio and the details of some of the debugging process.

I am creating an application (WPF and Console) in C# that is being developed on my workstation but I need to run/debug the application on another remote machine. Is there a way that I can just hit "Debug" from Visual Studio 2010 and have it emulate a run from the target machine? I need to do this because of local file directory access on the remote machine.

I have looked into remote debugging, but I think I am on the wrong track, as remote debugging just seems to use another machine to run the debugger, not the process itself.

Any information is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to use remote debugging..

Answer (score 2):

You will simply attach to process of the running application, for detailed explanation you should take a look at article

[Remote Debugging with Visual Studio 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146838/Remote-debugging-with-Visual-Studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot, but you can remote debug and attach to the app running on the remote machine, you will need the remote debugging tools installed on the remote machine

running (F5) on a remote machine, directly from within VS is possible in Dev11, however